# Change column name in sqlite when other tables have foreign keys to it

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, table-rename

I have a table named **groups**, and I want to rename one of its columns. Is was ok, so far. I know **sqlite** doesn't support renaming columns, so I did:

```
ALTER TABLE groups RENAME to tmp_groups;

CREATE TABLE groups(
    _ID integer primary key autoincrement,
    new_column_name integer
);

INSERT INTO groups(_ID, new_column_name) SELECT _ID, old_column_name FROM tmp_groups;

DROP TABLE tmp_groups;
```

But, when I drop the table **tmp_groups**, the table **members**, that had a foreign key with `ON DELETE CASCADE` has its records deleted as well, so I had to do the following:

1. Create a table **tmp_members** with the same columns as members, and without the foreign key;
2. Insert the records from **members** in **tmp_members**;
3. Drop the table **members**;
4. Run the code from the first part (with the **groups** table);
5. Re-create the table members with its foreign key;
6. Insert in **members** data from **tmp_members**;

Man, that was tiring! Its too much code to simply rename a column;

Is there any simpler way to handle this constraint problem, or is this the "sqlite way"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For historical reasons, SQLite allows to disable foreign key constraints (and this is even the default currently).

Just run [PRAGMA foreign_keys = off](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) before doing the `groups` table stuff.

---

It would also be possible to rename a column by using [PRAGMA writable_schema](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema), but you should do this only if you know what you're doing.

Comment: This worked for me on Android Sqlite. I ran the migrations and tested everything. When I turn foreign_keys on again, the delete cascade works. It simplifies a lot! Thanks